# create bottom bar

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, как сделать такой `bottom bar` с `circle button` посередине как на этой картинке?

[image: image demo]

Comment: Делаете верхнюю часть фона бара прозрачной, среднюю кнопку больше, две другие меньше

Answer (score 1):

В Constraint Layout можно привязать к низу экрана другой layout